# Multiple Schema or Single Schema for Cloud App?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring, database-schema

I've a question about how to manage database for clients for a Cloud App. I want to create a Cloud ERP on Spring and Hibernate but I'm not sure how to manage the database. Someone says me that should create a clone schema for every client to manage properly and secure the data, but I'm not sure that should be that 'cause that mean have a powerful database server. In the other hand exist the posibility to have a single schema to all users but that could be a lots of problem in management.

Please give me some advices.

Comment: Since it is an old question, you may have already addressed the issue. I would be glad to know what you did.

Answer (score 1):

If the data you are dealing with are totally different from customer to customer, then it is better to use cloned schemas for every customer.